# cant get comments to the facebook from the website

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

I am working for a website Development.When someone adds a comment to my website,comments are displaying in the website itself but not in their Facebook wall.Can you please give me any suggestion regarding this

Answer (score 0):

This feature is only in testing right now with Major Publishers according to http://techcrunch.com/2015/03/25/facebooks-new-comments-plugin-syncs-conversations-between-sites-and-fb-pages/

I'm also hoping it's released to everyone soon.